# Progress database array field -> Sql Server- accessing array value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am writing ETL jobs to move data between a progress database into an SQL server database (a working database- no the real end destination).

Some of the data in the Progress database are arrays, in that they are stored in a single varchar field, but delimited by semicolons. In the progress database, you access the array element as you would with many programming languages:
 SELECT
  fielda[1]
 FROM
  table

I am moving copies of these tables into SQL server and will be writing my transforms over this raw data. What is the best way to access these values? Is there an SQL sever function available whereby you give it a field and integer and it gives you the value? I know one would be trivial to write, but just thinking if theres something standard.

Thanks

Comment: Since we don't have array fields in SQL Server, any version, there's not going to be anything standard for you

Comment: Thanks. I realise that but I was hoping there is a function that you can pass an int in and get something at that position. For example, given `a;b;c`, a funciton such as `pos(field,2)` would return `b`.

Comment: If you're looking a splitting a delimited field, yes. I'm too lazy to go finding it but look for "splitting delimited column". The efficient solution will reference a numbers table.